# Why does Django ExtractWeekDay assign the same day to consecutive dates?

Tags: python, django

I have a model CustomerPurchase which records metadata about a purchase made.  I am trying to filter complaints that these purchases are attached to via a foreign key and related name tickets then group by weekday to find which days of the week have the most complaints.

I am running into an issue where I am having consecutive days listed as two different weekdays when using Django's ExtractWeekDay.  Why does this happen?

sample of my code:

```
from django.db.models.base import model
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay, Trunc

interval_type = 'days'

class CustomerPurchase(model):
    business = ForeignKey('data.Business', on_delete=CASCADE)
    VISIT_TIME_CHOICES = (
        ('L', 'Lunch'),
        ('M', 'Mid-day'),
        ('D', 'Dinner'),
        ('N', 'Late Night'),
        ('U', 'Unrecorded')
    )
    visit_time = CharField(max_length=1, choices=VISIT_TIME_CHOICES, default='U')

CustomerPurchase.objects.filter(business__company=1080, 
                                tickets__conversation__ci_priority__isnull=False
                                ).exclude(visit_time='U').annotate(
    day=ExtractWeekDay('tickets__created_at')
).values('day').annotate(
    date_value=Trunc('tickets__created_at', kind=interval_type, output_field=DateField())
)
```

the output of the above query:

```
<QuerySet [{'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 5, 30), 'count': 99}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 5, 31), 'count': 102}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 6), 'count': 92}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 7), 'count': 126}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 13), 'count': 104}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 14), 'count': 130}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 20), 'count': 64}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 21), 'count': 51}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 27), 'count': 51}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 6, 28), 'count': 95}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 4), 'count': 34}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 5), 'count': 37}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 11), 'count': 82}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 12), 'count': 86}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 18), 'count': 81}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 19), 'count': 92}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 25), 'count': 101}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 7, 26), 'count': 90}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 8, 1), 'count': 110}, {'day': 1, 'date_value': datetime.date(2021, 8, 2), 'count': 82}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

As you can see, the first two dates listed both show as day 1, but consecutive dates should not have the same weekday.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely due to some timezone issue where the items of 2021-5-31 are for example still 2021-5-30 in UTC time.

Comment: Oh, I see, so ExtractWeekDay does not account for timezones?

Answer (score 1):

This was as [willem-van-onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) suggested a timezone issue.  I fixed it by truncating the dates to remove the timezones before extracting weekdays.